# Kubernetes 403 Forbidden querying API with good RBAC credentials

Tags: api, kubernetes, http-status-code-403, rbac

**Final update**: Apparently there was some sort of issue with the variables defined in the `curl` command when redefined them after closing the connection to the cluster, command started working.

---

The setup is simple, on learning environment.
i created `ServiceAccount`, `Role` & `Rolebinding`

Trying to query pods or Services, i'm getting:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:myscript\" cannot list resource \"services\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
```

I don't know where i'm failing.
Originally i had only `get`, `list` and `delete` verbs. but even after using wildcard '*' keeps saying forbidden.

Here's some info from the cluster:

**Query command**: `curl -X GET $SERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/services --header "Authorization: Bearer $MYSCRIPT_TOKEN" --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`

```
ubuntu@master:~/$ kubectl describe sa myscript
Name:                myscript
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              myscript-token
Events:              <none>

ubuntu@master:~/$ kubectl get role script-role
NAME          CREATED AT
script-role   2022-09-04T10:44:22Z

ubuntu@master:~/$ kubectl get rolebinding script-rb -o wide
NAME        ROLE               AGE   USERS   GROUPS   SERVICEACCOUNTS
script-rb   Role/script-role   57m                    default/myscript

ubuntu@master:~/$ kubectl describe role script-role
Name:         script-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources         Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------         -----------------  --------------  -----
  pods              []                 []              [*]
  services          []                 []              [*]
  deployments.apps  []                 []              [get list delete]
```

**Update:**

few `can-i` commands that evidence RBAC should be good.

```
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl auth can-i get services --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
yes
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl auth can-i list services --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
yes
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl auth can-i delete services --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
yes
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl auth can-i delete deploy --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
yes
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl auth can-i update  deploy --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
no
```

`ServiceAccount` manifest.

```
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl get sa myscript -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-04T10:35:47Z"
  name: myscript
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "675592"
  uid: ab3b3c20-e3b9-405a-a9e9-e4f65ac13f5c
```

`Role` manifest

```
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl get role script-role -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"script-role","namespace":"default"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["pods","services"],"verbs":["get","list","delete"]},{"apiGroups":["apps"],"resources":["deployments"],"verbs":["get","list","delete"]}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-04T10:44:22Z"
  name: script-role
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "681508"
  uid: a1b03864-081e-4d0a-bf54-9c69f6f6c17e
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - services
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - delete
```

`RoleBinding` manifest

```
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl get rolebinding script-rb -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"RoleBinding","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"script-rb","namespace":"default"},"roleRef":{"apiGroup":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io","kind":"Role","name":"script-role"},"subjects":[{"kind":"ServiceAccount","name":"myscript","namespace":"default"}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-04T10:46:05Z"
  name: script-rb
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "676627"
  uid: dbdcef8f-6a30-4cd3-8152-2626c2284c83
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: script-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myscript
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 questions:

1. Can you share the manifests of `Role`, `RoleBinding` and `ServiceAccount`?
2. Are you able to verify the working of your `Role` & `RoleBinding` with ServiceAccount using the `kubectl auth can-i` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/)?

```
// kubectl auth can-i <verb> <resource> -n <namespace> --as system:service:<namespace>:<service-account-name> 
kubectl auth can-i get service --as system:serviceaccount:default:myscript
```

Comment: Updated with the requested! thanks.

Comment: Based on the outputs of your `can-i` commands, your role and rolebinding is working fine with the Service Account. Maybe there's something wrong with variables that you're passing in `curl -X GET $SERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/services --header "Authorization: Bearer $MYSCRIPT_TOKEN" --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`. Can you confirm if the values of `SERVER` & `MYSCRIPT` variables are getting passed correctly?

Comment: apparently there was something of those sorts. i had closed my connection to the AWS cluster, so reconnecting to check this, declared the Variables again, and now the command is working. yesterday when i posted the question i redefined the variables as well but nothing changed... so i'm not sure what happened here. 

Anyways, thanks for taking the time to help me.